# How to access SharePoint data outside SharePoint using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I want to access Sharepoint data from outside Sharepoint Context using javascript.Is there Anyway I can achive it?

I have tried the follwoing:

Created  a HTML Page On My Local File System.

```
file:///C:/Users/AD5009591/Desktop/TestRestApi.htm
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getlists() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                url: "http://syntwdd0005:5555/_vti_bin/ListData.svc",

                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="getdata" onclick="javascript:getlists();" />

</body>
</html>
```

but I am getting Error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because you need credentials to access documents in SharePoint. If i may advise you, first try to get Sarepoint credentials before trying to access documents.

Usually i use .NET (ASP) to get data from my SharePoint.

Comment: But is there any authentictaion technique we can use?or can we write our own Authnetication Module?

Comment: or Is there anyway we can Pass Authentication to sharepoint using javaScript